# Rxjs buffer implementation with backpressure

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

RxJS newbie question coming up!
So I have this basic buffer which appends everything from source1 and source2 to an array. Under certain conditions the buffer is cleared.

```
var buffer = Rx.Observable.merge(source1, source2).scan(
  function (arr, item) { 
    if (!magic) { 
      return arr.push(item); 
    }
    else { 
      return [item]; //Clear the buffer from previous items
    } 
  }, []);
```

I also want to have a "consumer" of the buffer, which shifts items from the buffer and does things with them. How do I implement that and make sure the consumer updates the buffer observable?

Edit: I want to feed the data into a [SourceBuffer](http://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/#sourcebuffer) but it is only allowed to append data to it while it is not updating. That gives me a backpressure situation I guess. So I did try to create a [controlled observable](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/controlled.md) but couldn't figure out how to create my own version of it, with my own buffering.

Comment: Please add some more details in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I have this basic buffer which appends everything from source1 and source2 to an array. Under certain conditions the buffer is cleared.

What you need to do here is:

```
var sourceStream = Rx.Observable.merge(soruce1, source2);

var boundary = sourceStream.lift(someOperator) // for example sourceStream.skip(3);
// someOperator is where you perform the "magic"

var subscribeToThisStream = sourceStream.buffer( boundary ); 
// emits all items collected in the buffer between two boundary emitions
```

> I also want to have a "consumer" of the buffer, which shifts items from the buffer and does things with them. How do I implement that and make sure the consumer updates the buffer observable?

If you wish to do that by means of a subscriber, **it is definitely not advisable if you want to do things the Rx way** and maybe even not possible in some cases.

Comment: Just a silly question - what is signature of `lift`? I cannot find it know,  but I'm pretty sure I've seen this method once in discussion about internal implementation of RxJS. So, how does it work?

Comment: Thanks for your answer tMJ, I have updated my question with some more details

Comment: @oskbor I am unable to see if you have got your answer or if you are still unclear about something. Let me know

Comment: @ErykNapierala whenever you apply any operator say `source.map(x => y)` it is internally expressed as `source.lift( new MapOperator( x=> y) )` (at least in the RxJava it is so, and I thin it would similar across all implementations)

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thanks! As far as I see, `lift` is implemented only in [RxJS Next](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS), current version doesn't provide this method in public API.